# Laravel 5.5.33 images not showing

Tags: php, image, laravel

I have tried many solutions from other posts already, but my images in a fresh laravel install are not working. I'm using laravel 5.5.33 at the moment.

I created a new folder in the PUBLIC folder called 'img'.
Inside of that I added an image called logo.jpg.
I have tried the following ways of showing that image on a clear  webpage.

```
            {{URL::to('/img/logo.jpg')}}
                (returns a string in the browser)
                In the shell it does say:
                [Sun Feb  4 23:38:14 2018] 127.0.0.1:52626 [200]: /img/logo.jpg
                [Sun Feb  4 23:38:14 2018] 127.0.0.1:52627 [200]: /favicon.ico

            <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/img/logo.jpg" alt="" />
                (returns nothing, empty, same result in the shell as above)

            <ing src="{{ asset('/img/logo.jpg' )}}"/>"
            {{ asset('/img/logo.jpg' )}}"
                (returns nothing in the browser, but gives a different response in 
                the shell:
                [Sun Feb  4 23:40:47 2018] 127.0.0.1:53086 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
                [Sun Feb  4 23:40:47 2018] 127.0.0.1:53134 [200]: /favicon.ico 
            {{ Html::image('img/logo.jpg') }}

                (returns a string and not an image in my browser: the string 
                says: http://127.0.0.1:8000/img/logo.jpg

            {{ HTML::image('img/logo.jpg') }}
                (returns a broken image icon)

            based on an answer i also tried:
            <img src="{{ asset('img/logo.jpg')}}" alt="" />
```

But it shows that broken images icon, and some image strings (not pictures)! (as text)

What I tried:
In the composer.json file I have:

```
{"require": {
"php": ">=7.0.0",
"fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
"laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
"laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
"illuminate/html": "5.*",
"laravelcollective/html": "5.5.*"
},
}
```

After adding that last line i run the composer update.

In the config/app.php I added:

```
          Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

(to the providers array)

and the following two to the aliases.

```
      'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
      'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

and even cleared the cache in various ways. (was another stackoverflow suggestion)

I tried:

- php artisan:clear
- php config:cache
- php config:clear

Comment: <ing src="{{ asset('/img/logo.jpg' )}}"/>"

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since you are using Laravel 5.5, you do not need to update your app.php, it will automatically discover the package for you.

Secondly, among the things you tried above was `<ing src="{{ asset('/img/logo.jpg' )}}"/>"`

I am sure that was a typo.
This is what I suggest you do instead:

```
<img src="{{asset('img/logo.jpg')}}" alt="your-alt-text">
```

Note that:

- There is no need for a '/' slash before the "img"
- You need to be sure that the image is indeed a jpg or a jpeg.

Try these and lets know the result.

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed.
I tried everything but nothing worked, then I installed a new php, laravel, composer etc on another machine, and everything worked as expected with the same code.

Turns out I was using a dated PHP version for everything on this machine. I updated it, reinstalled laravel and composer, and now it works as expected.